# Calculating coefficients when solving differential equation using power series

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Using power series, find a solution to the following differential equation:

$$(x + 2)y′(x) + 2y(x) = 0$$

that meets the condition that

$$y(\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{5}$$

I'm struggling with this, particularly when it comes to the step of working out the coefficients.
Here's what I have tried:

Isolating y(x) gives:

$ (x+2)y'(x)+2y(x)=0 \Leftrightarrow  y(x) = -\frac{1}{2}(x+2)y'(x)  $$

Setting $y(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_kx^k$, the constraint becomes (for k=0):

$$ y(\frac{1}{2})=c_0\frac{1}{2}x^0 \Leftrightarrow c_0 = \frac{1}{5} $$

So we get the following equality:

$$ y(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_kx^k = \frac{1}{5} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_kx^k \mbox{ 
   }(1)$$

The derivative of this is :

$$ y'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} kc_kx^{k-1} $$

and so

$$ -\frac{1}{2}(x+2)y'(x) =  -\frac{1}{2}(x+2) \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} kc_kx^{k-1} =  -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2}kc_kx^{k} - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} kc_kx^{k-1}$$

$$ = - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2}kc_kx^{k} - \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)c_{k+1}x^{k} $$

If we combine this with the y(x) in the form of (1) we get:

$$ \frac{1}{5} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_kx^k = - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2}kc_kx^{k} - \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)c_{k+1}x^{k} $$

Moving the middle term to the left hand side and adding up the series we get

$$ \frac{1}{5} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (1+\frac{k}{2}) c_kx^k = - \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)c_{k+1}x^{k}     $$

Here I need to compare the coefficients to get a general solution, but I can't understand how to do it.

Comment: You do usually a power series expansion around the initial point. Is there a reason given that this is not the case here? Set $x=\frac12+s$ and $u(s)=y(x)=y(\frac12+s)$ if you expect to make less errors with power series centered at $0$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Oh, I thought the initial point was irrelevant, as I just use it to find the value of $c_0$.  For k=0, $x^k$ will be 1 regardless, no?

Comment: You would have to solve $\frac15=\sum c_k2^{-k}$ involving all the coefficients of the series. That $2^{-0}=1$ helps only marginally. // In this case you can get a solution if you recognize the power series as a binomial or Newton series for $c_0(1+x/2)^{-2}$, but if the value function of the series is not known you will rarely get an exact solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let $t=x-1/2.$ Then $$(t+5/2) \frac {dy}{dt}+2y=0; \text { when } t=0, y=5/2$$. Let $$y=c_0+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}c_kt^k$$.Then $c_0=5/2.$ $$t \frac {dy}{dt}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kc_kt^k$$ $$(5/2) \frac {dy}{dt}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(5/2)kc_kt^{k-1}$$ $$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(5/2)(n+1)c_{n+1}t^n$$ $$=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(5/2)(k+1)c_{k+1}t^k$$ $$=(5/2)c_1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(5/2)(k+1)c_{k+1}t^k$$ Substitute all these expressions into the equation $$(t+5/2) \frac {dy}{dt}+2y=0$$ which must equal $0+0t+0t^2+0t^3+...$ Solve recursively for the $c_k$ by equating like powers of $t. $ Replace $t \text { by } x-1/2.$

Comment: Thanks a lot. One question: When you pull out $(5/2)1$ out on the fourth-to-ast line, how does that work?

Comment: It's a summation so I pulled out the term in $t^0$ since some of the other infinite summations started at $t^1$ and I wanted all the infinite sums to use the  same $t^k$ and start at the same value of$k$.

Comment: When $t=0$ then $x=1/2$ and thus $y=1/5$. You might conclude that when $t=-5/2$, $x=-2$ that the equation only allows the value $y=0$.